# Correctly managing color of bitmap image without creating anomalies on android device

Tags: android, image, colors, bitmap, color-profile

Working on Android fashion app and downloading various images from AWS Cloudfront, then storing them locally on internal storage.

The same **image looks different** if I show it from my app or from the gallery app. It's not about display, I'm sure of this because I tested with the Photoshop color picker.
I guess it may depend on compression but I have maximum value (100). Also, I tried to write directly array byte to my memory and decode the array without any compression.
Look this image to better understand:

[image]

I know that Android handles different color profile and I've tried many of those, with no effects.
Also, I use Glide library to load the images and I set no cache and ARGB8888 color profile.
Then I tried to use Picasso, but nothing changed.

That's how I download and save the images:
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
                try {
                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(strings[0]).getContent());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
        }

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            try {
                String filename = colorImage.getUniqueId() + "_zoom.jpg";

                // I tried this
                File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), filename);

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, false);

                // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                // But also this
                // File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), filename);
                // FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
                // FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, array);

                fos.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("mylog", "saveInternalStorageError(): " + e.getMessage());
                }
        }
    }
```

That's how I show the image (after I read all issues referenced here https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/515):

```
    Glide.with(this)
        .load(imageUriF)
        .asBitmap()
        .encoder(new BitmapEncoder(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100))
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .into(firstImage);
```

I also tried to show the image without Glide with same results

```
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    img.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

And Picasso too, with same results.

Have you got any idea about this issue?

Comment: Investigate if its about JPEG compression, its a lossly compression.

Comment: What do you suggest to debug the issue?
Is there a method to test without compressing the bitmap in order to isolate the issue?

Comment: Try to compress as PNG instead at first.

Comment: PNG format is much more limited as color gamut I dont think I can help us maintain the closest color to the original. Don't you think so?

Comment: JPEG changes the color on compression, PNG will keep it. RGB format is the same in both, only different color gamuts like sRGB, CMYK and etc needs specific formats.

Comment: Tested with PNG but the color still have different rgb numbers than when opened in the system gallery.

Comment: Check also if you need the flag described here on the component you do show the image https://developer.android.com/training/wide-color-gamut/index.html

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos wide color gamut flag is only available on Android O and we are using lower API version.